# How do I customize an article URL alias?

Tags: 6, path-aliases

In Drupal 6 there is a possibility to customize URL alias by the help of *[AUTOMATED ALIAS SETTINGS]*, but this will affect all the articles. I need to restructure my URL alias only for few paid articles.

Can we able to add /pro/ somewhere in the url only for few articles like as follows,

**Original article url parameters:**

www.example.com/{article}/{channel}/{year}/{month}/{nid}/{article_title}

**Customised article URL:**

www.example.com/pro/{article}/{channel}/{year}/{month}/{nid}/{article_title}

Comment: i think you are looking for https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto module

Comment: @Smalution : Thank you for your help, I have a question here, can we able to change article url only for few articles?

Comment: yes it provide the facility to set url for individual node

Answer (score 0):

There are so many module for this you can check

[Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)

[Path redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_redirect)

[Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect)